# Proof Checking: Prove there is an element of order two in a finite group of even order.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group of even order. Prove that there exists $a \in G$ such that $o(a)=2$.

I know this is a duplicate question, but I'm looking specifically to find out what, if anything, is wrong with my proof. My professor marked it as wrong, but my peers and I couldn't figure out *why* its wrong.

The proof I've come up with is as follows:

**Proof:** Let $G$ be a finite group of even order. Thus $|G|=2k$ for some $k \in \Bbb N$. By Lagrange's Theorem, $b^{|G|} = e$ for all $b \in G$. Thus, $b^{2k}=e$. $$\begin{align} b^{2k}=e &\Rightarrow b^{k \cdot 2}=e\\ 
&\Rightarrow (b^k)^2=e\\ &\Rightarrow a^2 =e \qquad for \;a=b^k\\&\Rightarrow o(a) =2\\\end{align}$$Thus, there exists an $a \in G$ such that $o(a)=2$. $\blacksquare$

Could anyone tell me where my mistake is?

Comment: How do you know that $a=b^k$ isn't the identity?

Comment: $a^2 = e$, but what if $a = e$? Then $o(a) = 1$, so it doesn't necessarily work. You'd need to either show $a \neq e$, or use a different approach.

Comment: For example:  in the Klein group of order $4$ you have $k=2$ in your notation. but every element satisfies $b^2=e$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that $a^2 = e$ does not imply that $a$ has order $2$. It implies that $a$ has order either $1$ or $2$. And if $a$ has order $1$ and $k$ is odd, all you can conclude is that $b$ has order $k$.

Comment: What about, (starting from $a^2=e$), suppose $o(a)=1$ then $a=e$. There must be at least one other element in the group, since the order is even. Suppose this element is $b$. By the same logic as in my work above, $b^2=e$, but if $o(b)=1$, then a=b, thus there exists a $b$ such that $o(b)=2$. Would that make the proof work?

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. There could be a whole ton of elements of order $2$, so the conclusion that $a = b$ doesn't follow.

Comment: I think maybe my logic didn't come across clearly just there. So, if $a=b$, then there would only be one element in the group, so $a\neq b$. Thus there is at least one element $b$ such that $o(b)=2$. So of course, there could be multiple elements with order 2, but my goal is only to show there is at least one.

Comment: @M.Yates You're mixing up $b$ and $b^k$ in your comments. I suggest you rewrite your proof with the correction you have in your mind. You should then see that the situation hasn't changed.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment, so I'll put it here: an element of order 2 is its own inverse.  If your group $G$ is finite, then try to pair up elements $g \in G$ with their *unique* inverses.  Using the fact that $G$ is even, you can argue that there has to be a nonidentity element which pairs up with itself.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your logic, which I almost bought, is as follows. Let the order of $G=2n$ and suppose that $b\ne e$ then it is true that $(b^n)^2 = e$ but all that show is that $b^n$ has order $1$ or $2$. It is possible that $b^n=e$.